# How do I use Symfony's Doctrine model classes outside of Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

Is there a way to use Doctrine using the model classes I've already setup for my Symfony applications without having to call Symfony with all that overhead?

This is more to satisfy a curiosity than anything else. For all the scripts I've used, I've just been able to instantiate Symfony (which typically turns out nice since I have all of the features that I'm used to working with on this particular project. But there has to be a way to load Doctrine and use the Symfony model classes without Symfony... Right?

Comment: You can download Doctrine separately at http://www.doctrine-project.org/ more info at http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/introduction.html -- but Doctrine is made up of two layers which appear to have separate downloads, the ORM and the DBAL, and it's not immediately clear to me how one would use the ORM (which is what I presume you want) without the DBAL. Perhaps it mentions this in the docs I linked.

Comment: Both layers are integrated into Symfony using the sfDoctrinePlugin plugin, I believe. But if I understand the inner workings of Doctrine properly, the ORM is the layer that turns the data abstracted by the DBAL and transforms it into PHP objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion there really isn't a way to use the model classes from Symfony elsewhere. With a little work, you can port over the classes to a new Doctrine model (even if you use the generator, since the main model class just extends the base which extends [sfDoctrineRecord](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/record/sfDoctrineRecord.class.php) (from the API docs, you can see which functions will need to be removed).

Otherwise, there isn't a practical way of doing that.

Anytime I need to access the Symfony model, I'm making a task or plugin since I do typically need part of Symfony's functionality.

As far as Symfony2 goes, just looking at the documentation makes me want to run screaming. It's not mature in any form or fashion (but, then again, neither is Symfony "legacy"). So, I'm not sure if the process would be any easier there.

Comment: Symfony2 is still under heavy development. There are only pre-releases and no stable version yet. It will be released in due course.

Comment: I'm actually excited about Symfony2, from the way its advertised on their site it's less of a resource hog than legacy 1.4. But, as you said, it is under heavy development which is why I haven't really took the time to look at it yet. It's almost like going back to Symfony 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

Doctrine isn't dependet on symfony. Doctrine is a "framework" on its own. It has it's [own](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/configuration.html) [autoloading](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/zh/introduction-to-models%3aautoloading-models) and can therefore work with it's classes like a regular PHP app. You can integrate Doctrine with other frameworks if you want ([like](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Using_Doctrine_with_Code_Igniter/) [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Using_Doctrine_with_Code_Igniter/) or [Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3411)). So you have every freedom you need without the need to do some tedious migration of your models/data/... from one system to another.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But Symfony has custom record and table classes which are extended from the front model classes, which is why I used the term "Symfony model class." Which is also why I posed the question in the first place. It may not be possible for that reason but users in the Symfony forum mention "don't do x so the user can use these classes outside of Symfony" and that piqued my curiosity. It would be nice to use my custom methods I've created within the model of my Symfony project from another project using Doctrine.